# Partial views in Sitefinity

Tags: templates, partial-views, sitefinity

Is there a way of having partial views that does not reload when I change click a link in Sitefinity?

I have this template and I want to keep header, menu and footer and change only the content.

```
<div class="sfPublicWrapper" id="header">
        @Html.SfPlaceHolder("headerPlaceholder")
    </div>

    <div class="sfPublicWrapper" id="menu">
        @Html.SfPlaceHolder("menuPlaceholder")
    </div>

    <div class="sfPublicWrapper" id="content">
        @Html.SfPlaceHolder("contentPlaceholder")
    </div>

    <div class="sfPublicWrapper" id="footer">
        @Html.SfPlaceHolder("footerPlaceholder")
    </div>
```

Any idea how to achive this?

Comment: you better just create pages based on this template and they will all share the same header and footer, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying different template setups I came into the conclusion it´s not possible with the MVC based templates to have fixed parts of the page that will not re-render after clicking on the menu. There are some implementations that can optimize how the page render and how the cache is managed. 
https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/administration-cache-settings

Template best pratices
https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/custom-themes-and-templates-preparing-your-work-environment

bundling and minification
https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/administration-enable-asp-net-bundling-and-minification